# Unable to get newly added rows from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, socket.io

After running my app - "node server.js" and connecting to the website for the first time, I'm able to get information from the database, emit them and append them on the website. But when I add a new set of information using the form on the Front-End and I hit refresh, the new information doesn't get appended unless I end my node app and re-launch it.

Find below the code.

**INDEX.HTML**

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>

            <head>
                <title>PIPROOM</title>
                <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=1">
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="semantic/dist/semantic.min.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
            </head>

            <body class="hidden">
                <div class="ui text container">
                    <form class="ui form" id="messageForm">

                        <div class="fields">

                            <div class="three wide field">
                                <label>CURRENCY PAIR</label>
                                <div class="field">
                                    <select class="ui fluid search dropdown" id="currency">
                                        <option value="EUR/USD">EUR/USD</option>
                                        <option value="GBP/USD">GBP/USD</option>
                                        <option value="USD/JPY">USD/JPY</option>
                                        <option value="USD/CHF">USD/CHF</option>                            
                                        <option value="USD/CAD">USD/CAD</option>                            
                                        <option value="NZD/USD">NZD/USD</option>                            
                                        <option value="AUD/USD">AUD/USD</option>
                                        <option value="GBP/AUD">GBP/AUD</option>
                                        <option value="GBP/JPY">GBP/JPY</option>
                                        <option value="GBP/NZD">GBP/NZD</option>
                                        <option value="GBP/CAD">GBP/CAD</option>
                                        <option value="EUR/JPY">EUR/JPY</option>
                                        <option value="EUR/CAD">EUR/CAD</option>
                                        <option value="EUR/AUD">EUR/AUD</option>
                                        <option value="EUR/GBP">EUR/GBP</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="three wide field">
                                <label>TRANSACTION</label>
                                <div class="field">
                                    <select class="ui fluid search dropdown" id="transaction">
                                        <option value="BUY">BUY</option>
                                        <option value="SELL">SELL</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="three wide field">
                                <label>ENTRY</label>
                                <div class="field">
                                    <input class="form-control" id="figure" rows="3">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="three wide field">
                                <label>LIMIT</label>
                                <div class="field">
                                    <input class="form-control" id="limit" rows="3">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="three wide field">
                                <label>STOP</label>
                                <div class="field">
                                    <input class="form-control" id="stop" rows="3">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <br>

                        <input id="submit" type="submit" class="fluid ui primary submit button" value="POST" disabled/>

                    </form>
                    <br>
                    <div class="chat" id="chat"></div>
                    <div class="notes" id="notes"></div>
                </div>

                <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
                <script src="semantic/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
                <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
                <script src="js/form.js"></script>
                <script src="js/chat.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $("body").removeClass('hidden');
                    });
                </script>
            </body>

            </html>
```

**CHAT.JS**

```
            $(function() {
                var socket = io.connect();
                var $messageForm = $('#messageForm');
                var $figure = $('#figure');
                var $limit = $('#limit');
                var $stop = $('#stop');
                var $transaction = $('#transaction');
                var $currency = $('#currency');
                var $chat = $('#chat');
                var $pipbox = $('#pipbox');
                var $transac = $('#transac');
                var mySound = new Audio('/sounds/bell.mp3');
                mySound.load();


                $messageForm.submit(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    socket.emit('send transaction', $transaction.val());
                    socket.emit('send currency', $currency.val());
                    socket.emit('send figure', $figure.val());
                    $figure.val('');
                    socket.emit('send limit', $limit.val());
                    $limit.val('');
                    socket.emit('send stop', $stop.val());
                    $stop.val('');
                });


                socket.on('new transaction', function(data) {
                    $chat.prepend('<div id="pipbox" style="margin-bottom: 0.8em;" class="ui blue inverted link relaxed segment">' + "<h2 id='transac' class='ui center aligned header'>" + data.msg + "&nbsp;&nbsp;" + "</h2>" + '</div>');
                });

                socket.on('new currency', function(data) {
                    $(transac).append(data.msg);
                    $("h2").removeAttr('id');
                });

                socket.on('new figure', function(data) {
                    $(pipbox).append("<center><h4 id='figs'>" + "ENTRY: " + data.msg);
                });

                socket.on('new limit', function(data) {
                    $(figs).append("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;LIMIT: " + data.msg);
                });

                socket.on('new stop', function(data) {
                    $(figs).append("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;STOP: " + data.msg + "</h4></center");
                    $("h4").removeAttr('id');
                    $("div").removeAttr('id');
                    $('#submit').prop("disabled", true);
                    mySound.play();
                });

                // append chatlog//

                // Initial set of notes, loop through and add to list
                socket.on('initial trans', function(data) {
                    var html = ''
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        // We store html as a var then add to DOM after for efficiency
                        html += '<li>' + data[i].tran + '</li>'
                    }
                    $('#notes').append(html)
                })

                // Initial set of notes, loop through and add to list
                socket.on('initial curs', function(data) {
                    var html = ''
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        // We store html as a var then add to DOM after for efficiency
                        html += '<li>' + data[i].cur + '</li>'
                    }
                    $('#notes').append(html)
                })

                // Initial set of notes, loop through and add to list
                socket.on('initial figs', function(data) {
                    var html = ''
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        // We store html as a var then add to DOM after for efficiency
                        html += '<li>' + data[i].fig + '</li>'
                    }
                    $('#notes').append(html)
                })

                // Initial set of notes, loop through and add to list
                socket.on('initial lmts', function(data) {
                    var html = ''
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        // We store html as a var then add to DOM after for efficiency
                        html += '<li>' + data[i].lmt + '</li>'
                    }
                    $('#notes').append(html)
                })

                // Initial set of notes, loop through and add to list
                socket.on('initial stps', function(data) {
                    var html = ''
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        // We store html as a var then add to DOM after for efficiency
                        html += '<li>' + data[i].stp + '</li>'
                    }
                    $('#notes').append(html)
                })

            });
```

**SERVER.JS**

```
            var express = require('express');
            var app = express();
            var server = require('http').createServer(app);
            var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
            var mysql = require('mysql');
            var trans = [];
            var isInitTrans = false;
            var curs = [];
            var isInitCurs = false;
            var figs = [];
            var isInitFigs = false;
            var stps = [];
            var isInitStps = false;
            var lmts = [];
            var isInitLmts = false;


            users = [];
            connections = [];

            var db = mysql.createConnection({
                host: 'localhost',
                user: 'root',
                password: 'bluestork3308',
                database: 'piproom'
            });

            db.connect(function(err) {
                if (err) console.log(err)
            })


            server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
            console.log('Server running...');

            app.use('/semantic', express.static(__dirname + '/semantic'));
            app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/css'));
            app.use('/sounds', express.static(__dirname + '/sounds'));
            app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/js'));

            app.get('/', function(req, res) {
                res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
            });

            io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
                connections.push(socket);
                console.log('Connected: %s sockets connected', connections.length);

                socket.on('disconnect', function(data) {
                    connections.splice(connections.indexOf(socket), 1);
                    console.log('Disconnected: %s sockets connected', connections.length);
                });

                socket.on('send transaction', function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    io.sockets.emit('new transaction', {
                        msg: data
                    });
                    db.query('INSERT INTO trans (tran) VALUES (?)', data)
                });

                socket.on('send currency', function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    io.sockets.emit('new currency', {
                        msg: data
                    });
                    db.query('INSERT INTO curs (cur) VALUES (?)', data)
                });

                socket.on('send figure', function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    io.sockets.emit('new figure', {
                        msg: data
                    });
                    db.query('INSERT INTO figs (fig) VALUES (?)', data)
                });

                socket.on('send limit', function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    io.sockets.emit('new limit', {
                        msg: data
                    });
                    db.query('INSERT INTO lmts (lmt) VALUES (?)', data)
                });

                socket.on('send stop', function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    io.sockets.emit('new stop', {
                        msg: data
                    });
                    db.query('INSERT INTO stps (stp) VALUES (?)', data)
                });

                if (!isInitTrans) {
                    db.query('SELECT * FROM trans')
                        .on('result', function(data) {
                            trans.push(data)
                        })
                        .on('end', function() {
                            socket.emit('initial trans', trans)
                        })

                    isInitTrans = true
                } else {
                    // Initial notes already exist, send out
                    socket.emit('initial trans', trans)
                }


                if (!isInitCurs) {
                    db.query('SELECT * FROM curs')
                        .on('result', function(data) {
                            curs.push(data)
                        })
                        .on('end', function() {
                            socket.emit('initial curs', curs)
                        })

                    isInitCurs = true
                } else {
                    // Initial notes already exist, send out
                    socket.emit('initial curs', curs)
                }


                if (!isInitFigs) {
                    db.query('SELECT * FROM figs')
                        .on('result', function(data) {
                            figs.push(data)
                        })
                        .on('end', function() {
                            socket.emit('initial figs', figs)
                        })

                    isInitFigs = true
                } else {
                    // Initial notes already exist, send out
                    socket.emit('initial figs', figs)
                }


                if (!isInitLmts) {
                    db.query('SELECT * FROM lmts')
                        .on('result', function(data) {
                            lmts.push(data)
                        })
                        .on('end', function() {
                            socket.emit('initial lmts', lmts)
                        })

                    isInitLmts = true
                } else {
                    // Initial notes already exist, send out
                    socket.emit('initial lmts', lmts)
                }


                if (!isInitStps) {
                    db.query('SELECT * FROM stps')
                        .on('result', function(data) {
                            stps.push(data)
                        })
                        .on('end', function() {
                            socket.emit('initial stps', stps)
                        })

                    isInitStps = true
                } else {
                    // Initial notes already exist, send out
                    socket.emit('initial stps', stps)
                }

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem. i dont know why but with mysql2 it seem to work.. 
var mysql = require('mysql2');

https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2